# Merging two MySQL Tables SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to "merge" two tables and have found a few examples but I'm having difficulty applying them as it continues to say I have syntax error:

```
UPDATE T2
SET payable_id = T1.payable_id, payable_type = T1.payable_type
FROM payments_distributions AS T2
JOIN payables AS T1
  ON T1.payments_distribution_id = T2.id
```

It mentions that the FROM is at an invalid position at the moment.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of 'merge' in this context. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `SET` clause to the end and all of the table references after `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE payments_distributions t2
       INNER JOIN payables t1
                  ON t1.payments_distribution_id = t2.id
       SET t2.payable_id = t1.payable_id,
           t2.payable_type = t1.payable_type;
```